# Como puedo heredar datos de una clase Padre hacia otra?

Tags: python

Como puedo heredar un dato de una clase Padre, hacia a otra ? Estoy solicitando al usuario que ingrese por medio de un `input` los datos en la clasePadre, pero necesito que el dato introducido vaya para la otra clase, el dato es `Nacionalidad`, como puedo hacer ?

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = None
        self.apellido = None
        self.nacionalidad = None

    def obtener_datos(self):
        self.nombre = input(" Nombre: ")
        self.apellido = input("Apellido: ")
        self.nacionalidad = input("Nacionalidad: ")


    def saludando(self):
        sal = ("Hola soy {} mi apellido es {} y mi nacionalidad es {}")
        print(sal.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad))

class Italiano(Persona):
    def __init__(self):
        Persona.__init__(self, nacionalidad)
        self.idioma_principal = None
    

    def obtener_datos1(self):
        self.idioma_principal = input("Introducir Idioma: ")
        

    def saludar(self):
        s = ("Ciao, sono {} il mio cognome è {} e la mia nazionalità è {} essendo la mia lingua {}")
        print(s.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad, self.idioma_principal))

pantalla = Persona()
pantalla.obtener_datos()
pantalla.saludando()


pantalla1 = Italiano()
pantalla1.obtener_datos1()
pantalla1.saludar()
```

Comment: Si he entendido bien, necesitas que la propiedad `nacionalidad ` se inicialice en la clase `Italiano` en este caso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin reestructurar demasiado tu código, tienes dos importantes fallos:

1. Estás usando diferente nombre en las funciones de la clase hija que en la clase padre, cuando se entiende que esas funciones son "las mismas" (extendidas en el caso de la clase hija, o reemplazando el comportamiento de la clase padre). Me refiero a la función `obtener_datos()` (que en la clase hija se extiende para pedir un dato más) y la función `saludando()` (que en la clase hija reemplaza a lo que había en la clase padre)
2. Para extender una función debes antes llamar a la de la clase padre, antes de ejecutar el código propio de la clase hija (o en algunos casos puedes hacerlo al revés)
3. Para invocar métodos en la clase padre es más genérico usar `super()` en lugar del nombre de la clase padre.

Con estas ideas en mente, las modificaciones a tu código (todos los cambios afectan solo a la clase hija, `Italiano`) serían:

1. Nombrar los métodos con el mismo nombre que en la clase padre
2. Usar `super()` en vez de `Persona` en `__init__()` (y entonces ya no es necesario pasar `self`)
3. Usar `super()` también en `obtener_datos()` para ejecutar la del padre y así obtener los datos comunes, antes depedir el dato específico del idioma.

Es decir:

```
class Italiano(Persona):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.idioma_principal = None
    

    def obtener_datos(self):
        super().obtener_datos()
        self.idioma_principal = input("Introducir Idioma: ")
        

    def saludando(self):
        s = ("Ciao, sono {} il mio cognome è {} e la mia nazionalità è {} essendo la mia lingua {}")
        print(s.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad, self.idioma_principal))
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
pantalla = Italiano()
pantalla.obtener_datos()
pantalla.saludando()
```

Y en la consola verás (por ejemplo):

```
Nombre: Giovanni
Apellido: Testa
Nacionalidad: Italiano
Introducir Idioma: Italiano
Ciao, sono Giovanni il mio cognome è Testa e la mia nazionalità è Italiano essendo la mia lingua Italiano
```

### ¿Por qué funciona?

Porque `self`, ya sea en el interior del código de `Persona` o en el interior del código de `Italiano`, se refiere **al objeto** que en ese momento se está usando, es decir, al objeto `pantalla` en este caso. Por tanto se están asignando los atributos `pantalla.nombre`, `pantalla.apellidos`, `pantalla.nacionalidad` y `pantalla.idioma`. Todo son atributos del mismo objeto. Es erróneo pensar que desde una clase padre accedas a atributos de una clase hija. Simplemente accedes a atributos del objeto que en ese momento se esté manejando (el cual pudo crearse a través de una clase hija como es este caso).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el constructor para trasmitirle los datos usando los atributos, ver el "código principal" para referenciar los [tag#]:

- [tag2]: Agregas los atributos con el constructor, puedes asociar un valor por defecto a la vez.
- [tag3]: Similar al inciso anterior, esta vez usas como atributo la instancia que contenga los datos de la persona ('pantalla' en este caso)
- [tag3.2]: Dentro del constructor de la clase "Italiano" defines los atributos de la clase padre "Persona", introduciéndole los atributos que recibe.
- [tag5]: En esta línea compartes los datos de la instancia "pantalla" para que los utilice en su plantilla interna de la estructura que heredó.

*Nota: las variables de pantalla y pantalla1 no están asociadas, puedes confirmarlo con el siguiente código al final:

```py
pantalla.nombre="jaja"
print(pantalla.nombre)
print(pantalla1.nombre)
```

#### Código principal

```py
class Persona:
    def __init__(self,nombre=None,apellido=None,nacionalidad=None): # [tag2] Agregar parámetros
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.nacionalidad = nacionalidad

    def obtener_datos(self):
        self.nombre = input(" Nombre: ")
        self.apellido = input("Apellido: ")
        self.nacionalidad = input("Nacionalidad: ")


    def saludando(self):
        sal = ("Hola soy {} mi apellido es {} y mi nacionalidad es {}")
        print(sal.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad))

class Italiano(Persona):
    def __init__(self,persona): # [tag3] Agregar como parámetro la instancia de Persona
        Persona.__init__(self, persona.nombre,persona.apellido,persona.nacionalidad) # [tag3.2] Llamar el constructor de Persona con parámetros
        self.idioma_principal = None
    

    def obtener_datos1(self):
        self.idioma_principal = input("Introducir Idioma: ")
        

    def saludar(self):
        s = ("Ciao, sono {} il mio cognome è {} e la mia nazionalità è {} essendo la mia lingua {}")
        print(s.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad, self.idioma_principal))

pantalla = Persona()
pantalla.obtener_datos()
pantalla.saludando()


pantalla1 = Italiano(pantalla) # [tag5] Introducir como parámetro la instancia pantalla en la clase Italiano
pantalla1.obtener_datos1()
pantalla1.saludar()
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de manejar el caso es pedir primero los datos y luego generar el objeto apropiado.

La implementación se puede realizar a través de un método que pide los datos, retornado el objeto correctamente creado.

Como regla general, es mala práctica hacer entrada/salida dentro de un objeto, por lo que he eliminado los `input` y `print`. En su lugar, el constructor recibe nombre, apellido y nacionalidad.

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.nacionalidad = "catalana"
        self.idioma_principal = "catalan"

    def saludar(self):
        sal = ("Hola soy {} mi apellido es {} y mi nacionalidad es {}")
        return sal.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad)


class Italiano(Persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        Persona.__init__(self, nombre, apellido)
        self.nacionalidad = "italiana"
        self.idioma_principal = "italiano"

    def saludar(self):
        s = ("Ciao, sono {} il mio cognome è {} e la mia nazionalità è {} essendo la mia lingua {}")
        return s.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.nacionalidad, self.idioma_principal)

def obtener_persona():
    nombre = input(" Nombre: ")
    apellido = input("Apellido: ")
    nacionalidad = input("Nacionalidad: ")

    if nacionalidad == "italiana":
        return Italiano(nombre, apellido)
    else:
        return Persona(nombre, apellido)


persona = obtener_persona()
print(persona.saludar())
```

produce:

```
 Nombre: Italo
Apellido: Jovani
Nacionalidad: italiana
Ciao, sono Italo il mio cognome è Jovani e la mia nazionalità è italiana essendo la mia lingua italiano

Process finished with exit code 0
```